# How do I determine my screen's current color temperature in KDE Plasma environment?

Tags: command-line, 18.04

OS: Kubuntu 18.04

I know how to change my screen color temperature but I want a method to determine the **current** screen color temperature, preferably via the command-line so that I may potentially use the command in a script.

Comment: Yes, I use `sct`.

Comment: `redshift` provides an option `-p` to “print parameters”, but in my tests it didn‘t work with either `sct` or `xflux`. The latter unfortunately doesn’t have an option like that, although the [Linux f.lux GUI](https://justgetflux.com/linux.html) *does* show the current color temperature, see [this screenshot](https://justgetflux.com/images/f.lux-linux.png).

Comment: For both `redshift` and `xflux` I could only find a way to determine the current night temperature *setting*, with `redshift -p|&grep -oP 'Color\D+\K\d+'` or `gconftool -g /apps/fluxgui/colortemp` (only if using [the GUI](https://github.com/xflux-gui/fluxgui/#install-instructions)!) respectively, but that doesn’t really help, or does it?